# IIS OutOfMemory exception after crash restart

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, out-of-memory, blazor

I recently upgraded project from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 5. After putting app on production I discovered few errors.. fixing them asap. However I noticed after app is crashed and started again I am getting OOM exception. I have to go kill process manually

Project description: Front-end runs on Blazor Server-side. Administration runs on Blazor WebAssembly.

IIS app pool setting (default setting except):

- No managed code
- AlwaysRunning
- Idle Time-out (0)
- Load User Profile (true)
- Regular Time Interval (0)

Version: .NET 5.0.6

Server OS: Win Server 2016 x64

I have quite interesting log since web app started. Usually takes 150 MB at start. In few requests its getting 300 MB (in-memory caching) as long there are not enought users.

```
2021-06-13 15:17:55.382 +02:00 [INF] Starting web host
2021-06-13 15:17:55.941 +02:00 [INF] Queued Hosted Service is starting.
2021-06-13 15:18:03.225 +02:00 [ERR] An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
React.Exceptions.BabelException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
 ---> System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at System.Threading.Thread.StartInternal()
   at System.Threading.Thread.Start()
   at React.ReactEnvironment.ExecuteWithBabel[T](String function, Object[] args)
   at Blazor.Polyfill.Server.BlazorPolyfillMiddlewareExtensions.Transform(String input, String filename, String babelrcJSON)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Blazor.Polyfill.Server.BlazorPolyfillMiddlewareExtensions.Transform(String input, String filename, String babelrcJSON)
   at Blazor.Polyfill.Server.BlazorPolyfillMiddlewareExtensions.GetPatchedBlazorServerFile()
   at Blazor.Polyfill.Server.BlazorPolyfillMiddlewareExtensions.CacheBlazorPolyfillLib()
   at Blazor.Polyfill.Server.BlazorPolyfillMiddlewareExtensions.<>c.<UseBlazorPolyfill>b__10_0(HttpContext context, Func`1 next)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<Use>b__1(HttpContext context)
   at React.AspNet.BabelFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
2021-06-13 15:18:07.040 +02:00 [ERR] An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalOptionsExtension..ctor(RelationalOptionsExtension copyFrom)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Infrastructure.Internal.SqlServerOptionsExtension..ctor(SqlServerOptionsExtension copyFrom)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Infrastructure.Internal.SqlServerOptionsExtension.Clone()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalOptionsExtension.WithConnectionString(String connectionString)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder, String connectionString, Action`1 sqlServerOptionsAction)
   at Project.Startup.<ConfigureServices>b__4_0(DbContextOptionsBuilder options) in F:\ASP.NET Core\Project\src\Startup.cs:line 42
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<AddDbContext>b__0(IServiceProvider p, DbContextOptionsBuilder b)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.CreateDbContextOptions[TContext](IServiceProvider applicationServiceProvider, Action`2 optionsAction)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.<AddCoreServices>b__0(IServiceProvider p)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Project.Services.LayoutService.<AddLayoutDataAsync>b__7_9(ICacheEntry entry) in F:\ASP.NET Core\Project\src\Services\LayoutService.cs:line 42
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.CacheExtensions.GetOrCreateAsync[TItem](IMemoryCache cache, Object key, Func`2 factory)
   at Project.Services.LayoutService.AddLayoutDataAsync() in F:\ASP.NET Core\Project\src\Services\LayoutService.cs:line 36
   at Project.Pages.Pages__Host.ExecuteAsync() in F:\ASP.NET Core\Project\src\Pages\_Host.cshtml:line 10
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, Boolean invokeViewStarts)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|29_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapWhenMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapWhenMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapWhenMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at React.AspNet.BabelFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
```

Honestly I think there is an issue in IIS. Is there posibility of corruption app pool/site?

Server free RAM is 15 GB. I heard someone had issue with RAM paging. I am using managed by windows on second disk - size of page 6 GB.

If you need more info let me know in comments. Thanks.

EDIT: startup.cs

public class Startup
{
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
Configuration = configuration;
}

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options => { options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), x => x.UseQuerySplittingBehavior(QuerySplittingBehavior.SingleQuery)); }, ServiceLifetime.Transient);

    services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(options =>
    {
        options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
        options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
        options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 0;
        options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
        options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;

        options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        options.Tokens.EmailConfirmationTokenProvider = TokenOptions.DefaultEmailProvider;
    }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<DatabaseContext>()/.AddDefaultTokenProviders().AddErrorDescriber<IdentityErrorDescriberLocalization>();
    
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddControllersWithViews().ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
    {
        options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
    }).AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
    });
    services.AddServerSideBlazor().AddCircuitOptions(options =>
    {
        options.DetailedErrors = true;
    });

    services.AddMemoryCache();
    services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
    services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    });
    services.AddSignalR();
    services.AddSweetAlert2();
    services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage();
    services.AddHttpClient();
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });
    services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie();

    services.AddAuthorization();

    // Add application services.
    services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, IdentityAuthenticationStateProvider>();
    services.AddScoped<RouteHelper>();
    services.AddScoped<GoogleAnalytics>();
    services.AddScoped<EmailBuilder>();
    services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
    
    services.AddTransient<AuthorizeService>();
    services.AddTransient<BannerService>();
    services.AddTransient<CategoryService>();
    services.AddTransient<HomeService>();
    services.AddTransient<MenuService>();
    services.AddTransient<ProductService>();
    services.AddTransient<SearchService>();
    services.AddTransient<SwitchService>();
    services.AddTransient<UserService>();
    services.AddScoped<DocumentHeadService>();
    services.AddScoped<ShoppingCartService>();
    services.AddScoped<UIService>();
    services.AddSingleton<LayoutService>();

    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter());
    }).AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();

    services.Configure<RouteOptions>(routeOptions =>
    {
        routeOptions.AppendTrailingSlash = true;
    });

    services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.ViewLocationExpanders.Add(new ThemeViewLocationExpander(Configuration.GetValue<string>("Theme")));
    });

    services.AddSingleton<IBackgroundTaskQueue, BackgroundTaskQueue>();
    services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, FeedScheduledTask>();

    // Hosted services
    services.AddHostedService<QueuedHostedService>();

    // Polyfill
    services.AddBlazorPolyfill();
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        app.UseHsts(); // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    }

    System.Globalization.CultureInfo customCulture = (System.Globalization.CultureInfo)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
    customCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";

    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = customCulture;

    app.UseSession();
    app.UseBlazorPolyfill();
    app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapBlazorHub(blazorOptions =>
        {
            blazorOptions.ApplicationMaxBufferSize = blazorOptions.TransportMaxBufferSize = 20 * 1024 * 1024;
        });
        endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
    });
}}
```

Blazor polyfill: https://github.com/Daddoon/Blazor.Polyfill

Comment: First step is to get a memory dump and look at whats in those 6 gigs.

Comment: It was mem leak fixed 6 months ago. Thats why I know it could allocate so much RAM. Now its throwing exception at 800 MB +-

Comment: Your error points to React and Babel, you should at least mention those in the tags and question. And post the entire Startup.cs .

Comment: @HenkHolterman Actually I dont think that's the issue. Cause its randomly throw over time to custom nuget packages like this one. I've added startup to post. React and Babel are registered by custom nuget package via "AddBlazorPolyfill". Link above. I am getting OOM from nuget packages that no one has issue with them. Which leads me back to IIS issue.

Comment: Is AddSession() even compatible with Blazor? (I don't know). Did you verify that for all those components you are stacking?  It's not an MVC app.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I kinda use controllers to cheat refresh-less login. Blazor server-side wont allow me to modify headers during connection, so I manually create my own HttpClient and post login request. Which worked perfectly during 3.1. Few moments ago I occured this error again during uploading new version. Using app_offline.htm to turn off web, then upload newer version. After turning on same error happened. However I turned web off and on -> no error. There is something weird going on.

Comment: So I made some futher research whats happening.. every time app crash restart results into OOM. I have to manually restart it by killing process, then it boots up normally.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have this OOM exception add this line to your csproj file under PropertyGroup section :

```
 <ServerGarbageCollection>false</ServerGarbageCollection>
```

this will improve the memory usage but better you need to use memory profiler in vs to check what an object is causing the memory leak in your application

Comment: Thanks, I will try. However I think I have fix for my memory leak.. HttpClient instances were not disposing. Still not in production so I cant tell for sure

Comment: @user1085907 did you solve the issue with the HttpClients?

Comment: @snaits It improved stability, however disposing HttpClient is not enough. There is some leak. Now its weekly crash instead daily. Turned off aswell server GC. It might help but its not solving the issue.

Comment: as i said you have to find the object that causing the memory leak using memory profiler if you cant find it as an alternative subscribe your app as a service and restart it after it crashes till you find the issue good luck bro

Comment: Its web app. So IIS makes reboot on crash. But sometimes it reboots faster than w3wp can clear memory

Comment: i know its a web app but if you can deploy it as a service on linux server using outofprocess hosting (nginx and  kestrel) the memory will be cleared faster i tested it i know its not the best solution because you have to find that memory leak at the end